# Using struct timeval in Python

Tags: python, ctypes, timeval

I have a C program containing a structure

```
struct S{
           int x;
           struct timeval t;
 };
```

and a function

```
int func(struct S s1, struct S s2)
```

I need to call this function from my python program.
I am using ctypes.The parallel structure on Python

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
class S(Structure):
        _fields_ = [("x",c_int),
                     ("t", ?)]
```

Now, my question is what will I write in the ? place and any dependencies related to it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My advice - it will work for a good number of platforms but not for all, make sure what is the OS Target and test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the definition of `struct timeval` in your platform's C include files (the Internet suggests `sys/time.h`), then transcode that into a ctypes structure.

On my platform a `struct timeval` is

```
struct timeval {
  long tv_sec;
  long tv_usec;
};
```

(and I suppose this is the standard anyway), so

```
class timeval(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("tv_sec", c_long), ("tv_usec", c_long)]

class S(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x",c_int), ("t", timeval)]
```

would probably fit the bill.

Comment: one more question.. does this structure(timeval) changes from platform to platform?

Comment: YES it changes, NetBSD 6.0 (or superior) in 64 bits for example. Be careful.

Comment: @tiago-peczenyj What is the smart way to deal with these platform dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

without any further info, it will be the definition of [timeval](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html):

```
class timeval(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("tv_sec",c_long),
                 ("tv_usec", c_long)]

class S(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x",c_int),
                 ("t", timeval)]
```